# What's this vegetable from the A-3013 jigsaw puzzle?

Tags: vegetables

It may be cultural, but nobody in our family seems to be able to identify the green vegetable on the right of the A-3013 wooden puzzle (made in China).

[image: A-3013]

Note that not everything is a vegetable on the board, but we were able to identify:

> white radish, carrot, corn, potatoes,
>    broccoli, tomato, ?,
>    pumpkin, eggplant, fennel, mushrooms

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is way out of scope of the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest that it's meant to be either [artichoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artichoke)...

[image: artichoke]

Or, more likely, [bamboo shoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_shoot)

[image: bamboo shoots]

By the way, I think the one you suggested could be fennel is more likely to be pak choi :)

[image: pak choi]

White radish (mooli) looks like this:

[image: mooli]

So the white thing top left may perhaps be [kohlrabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohlrabi) or just an ordinary turnip

[image: kohlrabi]

Comment: **Bamboo**! That must be bamboo, and that explains why we never saw any before. Thank you for the potential alternatives to white radish and fennel.

Comment: @Cœur yeah! The bamboo shoots we get in a can here look pretty much nothing like that. And TIL globe artichoke is a thistle. Thanks for the question ^_^